# Organising refactored code

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public class Vehicle
  'Not very well designed.  Contains properties and functions/subs for cars, buses, tractors, planes, drivers etc.
end class
```

I am wanting to refactor the code so  that there is a superclass (vehicle) and many subclasses.  I want to do this as I go along whilst working on much higher priorities.

If I create the new classes then there will be two Vehicle classes i.e. the refactored vehicle and the old vehicle.  I believe the best approach is to create a new namespace for the refactored code e.g. company.app.businesslogiclayer.automobiles.refactoredcode, company.app.datalogiclayer.automobiles.refactoredcode.  Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could treat your existing clas as a subclass since it already has some class-specific functionality in it and then look at the [Extract Superclass](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractSuperclass.html) refactoring. Here you would create your new super class and then move common features from the sub class to the super class.

[image]

[Refactoring for Visual Basic](http://books.google.com/books?id=vRxAnRb3mb4C&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=refactor+extract+superclass+vb&source=bl&ots=_oxrxktqYy&sig=Dmt2-ALJ3SXEBM5GTqeNaKWyTeQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LP72UOboEY788QSy0YHIBw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=refactor%20extract%20superclass%20vb&f=false) has a nice section on Extract Super Class that you might find interesting.

Comment: In my case Employee would be more like the superclass as it contains everything.  Do you think it would be ok to have a badly designed class as a superclass?

Comment: Yeah, I definitely see what you are saying.  As with all refactorings, it is important to tailor the steps to your individual codebase.  I think either approach would work.  Personally, I would try to think of my existing class as a subclass, that way you are forced to refactor common elements into a clean superclass.  However, I'm sure the other way would work as well, just make sure to clean up your Employee class at some point.  I'm saying all of this, of course, with no insight into your code base, so you should definitely do what you feel is right for your situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I am just looking at the link now.  Are you able to answer my other question (about refactoring) here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366815/reference-variables-contain-namespace

Comment: @w0051977 I answered your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to **not overuse inheritance**. "Driver" strikes me as something that you really want to use composition for. A vehicle has a driver. Similarly other things such as the might be better handled using composition. For instance you could have a car that can go 200km/h, and have one that can go 300km/h. Really do not want to have different classes for that. You could have a simple int value or a EngineBehaviour class if you have something more complex. (Keyword: **strategy pattern**) Also be sure to not instantiate such composite objects in your object but rather inject them (keyword: **dependency injection**).

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the reference to Strategy pattern. Are you able to answer my other question (about refactoring) here?: stackoverflow.com/questions/14366815/…