# Reference variables contain namespace

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I am trying to follow the advice of the answerer of this post: [What's the naming convention for classes in the DataAccess Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955875/whats-the-naming-convention-for-classes-in-the-dataaccess-project) (jdk).

Please take a look at the code below:

```
'Form1.vb
Imports WindowsApplication1.BusinessLogicLayerShared

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim IPerson As IPerson
        IPerson = New BusinessLogicLayer.Person()
        Dim name As String = IPerson.getName()
    End Sub
End Class

'Person.vb
Imports WindowsApplication1.BusinessLogicLayerShared

Namespace BusinessLogicLayer
    Public Class Person
        Implements IPerson

        Private IPerson As DataLogicLayerShared.IPerson

        Public Function getName() As String Implements IPerson.getName
            IPerson = New DataLogicLayer.Person
            getName = IPerson.getName
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace BusinessLogicLayerShared
    Public Interface IPerson
        Function getName() As String
    End Interface
End Namespace

'Person.vb
Imports WindowsApplication1.DataLogicLayerShared
Namespace DataLogicLayer

    Public Class Person
        Implements IPerson

        Public Function getName() As String Implements IPerson.getName
            'Connect to database and get name
            Return "Ian"
        End Function

        Public Function getAge() Implements IPerson.getAge

        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace DataLogicLayerShared
    Public Interface IPerson
        Function getName() As String
        Function getAge()
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

The client (form) calls the business logic layer and the business logic layer calls the data logic layer.  The name (String) is passed from the data logic layer to the business logic layer and back to the client.

I don't like the fact that when referencing a interface I have to specify the namespace e.g. Private IPerson As DataLogicLayerShared.IPerson.  Should I specify the namespace in the reference or can the pattern I have adopted be amended to avoid this?

Comment: @Frank, please would you take a look at the following post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/accept-an-answer-obligation.  I always mark an answer as answered or at least upvote it.  I regularly go back through my questions and mark those that have helped me.  I would not want to mark a question as answered unless I am sure it has helped me to avoid misleading others who may read the post in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add `Imports DataLogicLayerShared` at the top of your source file.  This will keep you from having to fully qualify each class with the namespace.

You can learn more about VB .NET references and namespaces [here](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/ref_ns.htm)

**Update:** If you have multiple classes or interfaces with the same name, in different namespaces, you will have to qualify which class you are using by adding the namespace before it as in your example above.

In your case, you probably don't need to include business layer and data layer classes in the same source file.  Your code should call the services (business logic) layer, which in turn calls the data layer.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question as the question was not about DataLogicLayer.Person.  The question is specifically about: BusinessLogicLayer.Person.  If I import DataLogicLayerShared and remove the namespace in the reference, then there will be two different versions of IPerson (one referencing DataLogicLayer.Person and the other referencing BusinessLogicLayer.Person)

Comment: Thanks.  In the question I provide a link.  In the link the answerer has an interface for the Data Access Layer class but no interface for the Business Logic Layer class.  I am unsure how the client calls the BLL class.  Can you make sense of it?

Comment: @w0051977 - I think it would be cleaner **not** to have two different Person classes.  What is different about the two classes?  I would think a single Person class that is used by both the business logic and data access layers would be better.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, the two different classes introduce two different layers i.e. one for the business logic and the other for data logic.

Comment: @Robert Greiner, are you able to answer the question in the forth comment under this answer? I should then be in a position to mark the question answered (your answer).

Comment: @w0051977 to call Customer in the business logic layer you would have to include `Com.Examle.MyProject.Business` and then new up a customer (`var customer = new Customer()`).  Then you could call `customer.GetData()`  The ICustomer interface was used in the Data Layer's Customer class.